# Serverless command return "This is serverless"?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, serverless

I have a python project (flask) with PostgreSQL, and I tried to run the command `sls wsgi serve`

And I got this kind of 'error'

[image]

Does anyone know why I got this?

Answer (score -1):

Solved, command `serverless wsgi serve` works